# Rspec use plain methods instead of be_ matchers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In model I have `own?` method, can I use it as is in rspec instead of `be_own`? Without writing custom matchers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It is easy:

```
model.own?.should == true
```